# gnome-screenshot copy to clipboard shortcut

Tags: shortcut-keys, screenshot

I use MATE as desktop viewer. How can I add a shortcut for taking a screenshot of a part of the windows and copy it to the clipboard? Basically what with gnome the command control-shift-stamp.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I found out the solution.
First, open the shortcut dialog window and press `add` to add a new shortcut. Then paste this code:

```
gnome-screenshot -a -c
```

For other useful gnome-screenshot command, from the terminal: `gnome-screenshot --help`

Comment: It would be good for other readers, if you accept your own answer (see [Can I answer my own question?](/help/self-answer)).

Comment: You have to do this manually starting in Gnome 41+ - what I'm finding is that occasionally my shortcut just stops working... but perhaps that's another issue to figure out.

Comment: -c doesn't do anything in Ubuntu 22.04 it seems. the image is not copied to the clipboard

Comment: @Hilikus нужно установить xclip (sudo apt install xclip)

Comment: In case you are trying to attach this command to a keyboard shortcut and find that it does not work, you can try using this instead `gnome-screenshot -acf /tmp/test`.

Answer (score 69):

There are a set of keyboard shortcuts in Ubuntu specifically for screenshots.

Go to *System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Screenshots*. In my case it is `Ctrl+Shift+Print_Screen`

[image: Keyboard Shortcuts]

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of this? (Or a little more detail?)

Comment: Just open settings, and into keyboard you find something like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/z1xXQ.png

Comment: "Copy a screenshot of an area to clipboard" has changed my life! My old workflow was to crop with GIMP. This is much better.

Comment: outdated answer

Answer (score 14):

For [Gnome](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/screen-shot-record.html.en), copying portion of the screen to clipboard is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScrn</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like they've recently removed this in the newest versions on GNOME, but you can reinstate it by combining some of the existing answers here, specifically:

1. Go to <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Keyboard</kbd> > <kbd>View and Customize Shortcuts</kbd> > <kbd>Custom Shortcuts</kbd>.
2. Click the <kbd>+</kbd> and create a new shortcut with:
   Command `gnome-screenshot -acf /tmp/gnome-screenshot-area`
   Shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Print</kbd>

Note: saving the screenshot to file is [intentional](https://askubuntu.com/a/1212806/125422) (thanks @grabantot).

Another note: I switched back to Wayland, which seems to have broken this method.

[image: Custom Shortcut]

Comment: The screenshot doesn't appear in the clipboard. I believe this is due to some issue with gnome that it doesn't preserve the values in clipboard after the application that added the value exits or something like that. Had a similar issue with using xclip in scripts.

Comment: Found the solution here https://askubuntu.com/a/1212806/626636

Comment: If you're having this issue after upgrading to Ubuntu 22, use this solution and change your window management to "Ubuntu Xorg". The way to do this is simple: logout as your user, then in the bottom right corner of the login screen click on settings and select "Ubuntu on Xorg".

Comment: @waykiki yes, the important part is using Xorg, rather than Wayland.

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues with getting the custom selection to copy to clipboard. What worked for me is: `gnome-screenshot --area -c`