# How to paste a screenshot into Pinta

Tags: screenshot, pinta

tI want to paste a screenshot into Pinta, so I press <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> (Print Screen) button on my laptop. But when I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> it into Pinta, Pinta says

```
Image cannot be pasted
The screenshot does not contain an image
```

What do I have to do? Thanks a lot

Comment: [This 14 votes answer solves it](https://askubuntu.com/a/597926/448595)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the screenshot in Pinta using the Open button in the Pinta toolbar.

1. Save a screenshot in a commonly used image format, like .png or .jpg.
2. Open Pinta and click the  Open icon in the top left corner.
3. A new **Open Image File** window will open. Browse to the screenshot and click the Open button in the lower right corner to open it in Pinta.

Comment: Oops. I don't know that Ubuntu automatically saves an image when I press PrtSc. I've just moved from Windows, so I thought it would save the sreenshot in clipboard rather in a png file. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: It's an answer to the question. We need a way to paste an image from clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Pinta now has a built in tool for taking screenshots.

File menu -> New Screenshot...

Comment: What if I want a screenshot of an area of the screen?