# GNOME Screenshot can't copy to clipboard in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome, shortcut-keys, clipboard, gnome-screenshot

I just freshly installed Ubuntu 18.04 and downloaded the latest updates. I'm having trouble taking screenshots to clipboard using the built-in `gnome-screenshot` tool. The default keyboard shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> don't appear to work (makes the shutter sound, but empty clipboard and nothing saved in Pictures folder either), and using `gnome-screenshot -c` in the terminal is similarly ineffective.

I've read that `gnome-screenshot` had clipboard issues with Wayland, but my understanding is that 18.04 defaults to Xorg. Checking my login settings, the default is "Ubuntu," with a secondary "Ubuntu on Wayland" option. I'm just using the default.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 use Xorg by default

Comment: Just to make sure, run `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` to check your session.

Answer (score 28):

Not sure if this is related - in my case (fresh Ubuntu 19.10), `gnome-screenshot -c` would put the captured image to the clipboard, but somehow I can only paste it in certain applications (e.g. Gimp) while not in others (e.g. Chrome).

Found a workaround by (assigning to a shortcut) this:

```
gnome-screenshot -acf /tmp/test && cat /tmp/test | xclip -i -selection clipboard -target image/png
```

Comment: Nice workaround.  Mine was working fine with Ubuntu 18.04 and when I recently upgraded to 20.04 it stopped working. Thanks for this solution.

Comment: To make this work with Ubuntu 20.04 Keyboard Shortcuts I had to wrap it `sh -c "gnome-screenshot -acf /tmp/test && cat /tmp/test | xclip -i -selection clipboard -target image/png"`

Comment: The above answer for Ubuntu 20.04/.10 is the only one that worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: I expanded the command to clean up the image from the tmp folder `sh -c "gnome-screenshot -af /tmp/clipboard-img.png && xclip -i -selection clipboard -target image/png /tmp/clipboard-img.png && rm /tmp/clipboard-img.png"`

Comment: I noticed that this actually seems to work just as `gnome-screenshot -acf /tmp/test`. I.e. just persisting to file seems to allow it to paste into apps like Chrome. This was a complete fluke, because I simply don't have `xclip` installed, but it still worked!

Comment: There is a similar solution for xfce4-screenshooter in xfce. It uses /dev/stdout to avoid the leak to /tmp.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/466278/xfce-screenshooter-and-clipboard-manager

Comment: Btw it needs to be a real file. `gnome-screenshot -acf /dev/null` will **not** work. Too bad...

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem in Ubuntu 20.04: `gnome-screenshot -a -c` was not copying to clipboard.

The solution was to ensure `xclip` was installed with:

```
sudo apt install xclip
```

- `gnome-screenshot` version = 3.36.0
- `xclip` version = 0.13-1

Comment: This is the correct solution!

Comment: Does not work in 22.04

Comment: @fffred I'm on ubuntu 22.04 and using `gnome-screenshot --area --clipboard -f /tmp/gnome-screenshot-bullshit` works to copy to the clipboard. No need to worry about the additional file as tmp is auto-cleaned up. But [it seems to be needed to make it work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196914/gnome-screenshot-cant-copy-to-clipboard-in-ubuntu-18-04#comment2466293_1212806)

Comment: @lucidbrot It does not work for me either

Answer (score 2):

My [workaround](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-screenshot/-/issues/66#note_1644396) is (for Ubuntu 2204, GNOME 42): Switching from wayland to xorg and made a custom keyboard shortcut with the following command:
`gnome-screenshot -a -c --file=/tmp/screenshot_tmp.png`

Answer (score 1):

Today I had a similar problem under Oracle Linux 8: It wouldn't copy to the clipboard. I could resolve this with running the command:

```
env GDK_BACKEND=x11 gnome-screenshot -i
```

Note the `x`, it is not capital X as usual!

You may enter `-c` instead of `-i`, of course. On this Oracle Linux 8 machine other applications couldn't create a window at all without the `GDK_BACKEND` setting.

Comment: How do you run this though?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> instead of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>.

Comment: This worked for me. It's also captured in the help section of the default Screenshot app. 

PS: I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on Ubuntu 20.04 but I couldn't get it working from a custom shortcut key.  I had to write a bash script.

Note: I also had to install `xclip` as shown in [Ben's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1263786/618353).

Here it is:

1. Run:

   ```
   nano screengrab.sh
   ```
2. Add the following text:

   ```
   rm -rf /home/user/Pictures/2.png 
   gnome-screenshot -acf /home/user/Pictures/2.png
   ```

   **Note:** Your PNG file can be named anything, just make sure you delete the same named file first and then it will be created each time by the `gnome-screenshot` app. If you don't delete it or you have the wrong file name each time, it will fail silently.
3. Save the file by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.
4. Make the script executable:

   ```
   chmod a+x screengrab.sh
   ```
5. Open Settings → *Keyboard* and add a new shortcut with the details shown in the image below:

   [image: shortcut keys]

Answer (score 0):

For people running a Wayland session, binding the following to a shortcut should work

```
gnome-screenshot -af /tmp/tmp_screenshot.png && wl-copy -ot image/png < /tmp/tmp_screenshot.png
```

Same principle as Ferrard is using really, just adapted for Wayland.

You need to have `wl-clipboard` installed.

Also, you might have to put this in a script and call that (I did, because my machine does not seem to like executing multiple commands in one shortcut, YMMV though).

Answer (score -1):

Try `find $HOME -name "Screenshot*"` to see if the screenshots are being saved in an unexpected location. Also check Settings|Keyboard Shortcuts. In a recently upgraded 20.04.1 (from 18.04) gnome-screenshot saved the png images in $HOME instead $HOME/Pictures as before.

Comment: As OP says in the title, the problem is not a file-system location but that the data doesnt end up on the clipboard