# Gnome Screenshot Copy Clipboard not working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, clipboard, screenshot

I've just upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 from 18.04. Gnome screenshot command does not work anymore. The command does not copy the screenshot to the clipboard.

```
gnome-screenshot -a -c
```

Comment: same problem with my 20.04 not with ctrl+prtsc and not with gnome-screenshot -a -c

Comment: I am finding it *sometimes* works. No idea why. Sometimes when I shift + printscreen THEN ctrl click it works.

Answer (score 13):

After months of banging my head and fingers, it is like so:

Main behavior:
Prtscn => Saves Full screen to folder [default ~/Pictures]

Modifiers

- +Ctrl => Saves to clipboard
- +Alt => Saves current window
- +Shift => Draws area to save

And all combinations.     [except alt + shift which behaves like alt alone]

For Example:
Ctrl + Shift + Prtscn will let you select area and save it to clipboard

Answer (score 12):

Please try with
<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>PrintSc</kbd>

In my case, the solution is in configuration > key combinations > search the command and update the key combination.
Currently, I take a screenshot area with shift + PrintSc and it is working for me!

Answer (score 9):

I found a workaround in https://askubuntu.com/a/1212806/1074472

```
gnome-screenshot -acf /tmp/test && cat /tmp/test | xclip -i -selection clipboard -target image/png
```

You need to have xclip installed.

Comment: Please add a warning that this leaks data through the `/tmp` folder.

On Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome, `gnome-screenshot -acf /tmp/tmp.png` is enough.

Comment: this works for me.

Comment: If you modify this to save to `Pictures/latest_screenshot.png` instead of the temp directory, it turns the "information leak" into an intentional feature where it saves to a file AND the clipboard.

Answer (score 6):

I think the issue has been there for a while. It is probably due to a bug in recent versions of gnome-setting-daemon, which clears data in clipboard when the app is closed. Thus, when the command `gnome-screenshot -a -c` runs and finishes, the screenshot is saved to clipboard and then cleared. That is the best guess for now.

For more information and updates, please refer to
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-screenshot/-/issues/66

Comment: That site gitlab gnome will not even allow logins to post. Totally broken now.

Comment: This is exactly the issue I'm running into using gnome-screenshot in i3. Verified by using the "Copy to Clipboard" functionality from gnome-screenshot -a , hitting the "Copy to Clipboard" button and testing it in GIMP (worked), then closing the process and seeing that my clipboard was empty by trying to paste it again in GIMP.

Answer (score 4):

My solution (Ubuntu 20.04.1) was to use only the first part of Faith Baltaci's answer:

`gnome-screenshot -acf /tmp/test && cat /tmp/test`

Comment: I can confirm this works in `Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS`

Answer (score 1):

Why not try `Ctrl + Alt + PrintScreen`. This copies the image into the clipboard instead of saving it in Pictures.

Comment: `Ctrl + Shift + PrintScreen` If you'd like to select a certain area of your screen and put it in clipboard.

Comment: are WE , the users , waiting for "act of congress" to get this WHERE is used to be  - working ! ( Are "Inmates  (still ) running the asylum ?" AKA HOW did the WORKING macro got changed?

Answer (score 0):

On my Ubuntu 22.04, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Prt Scr</kbd> shortcut does not work if the Screenshot program is closed. This seems to be a bug, which didn't happen on my last Ubuntu 22.04 machine.

My solution was to start the Screenshot program (gnome-screenshot) on startup, by adding this command as a startup application:

```
gnome-screenshot --interactive
```

I leave the application running in the background and I can now use the shortcut again, for quick and easy screenshots to clipboard.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**Ubuntu 22.04**

`shift + ctrl + alt + r` opens Record a screencast interactiveley

go to **Settings** > **Keyboard** > **Keyboard shortcuts** > **Screenshots**

[image]

Comment: The question asks about how to copy screenshot to the clipboard. This answer says a different thing.

Comment: @Puspam you are right, it's just an alternative solution.