# Copy window screenshot to clipboard not working

Tags: gnome, screenshot

I have a screenshot issue on Ubuntu 20.04.
I can copy the box selection screenshot to the clipboard and the whole screen to the clipboard, but I cannot copy the window screenshot to the clipboard with the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrintSc</kbd>. The <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrintSc</kbd> shortcut works and save a window screenshot. My <kbd>alt</kbd> key works perfectly too.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can't reproduce that. For me it works on Ubuntu 21.10. But then, you did not provide information on your Ubuntu version, desktop you use and on your hardware.

Comment: Deleted my unhelpful answer so your question will show as unanswered. Sorry for wasting your time! Things to add to your question - (1) Ubuntu version; (2) can you save a screenshot with Alt-PrtSc?; (3) does Alt with anything else function? (eg try Alt +f2 to open a terminal window.) That will help determine if it might be a problem with the Alt key or its mapping.

Comment: There is a solution here
`gnome-screenshot -acf /tmp/test && cat /tmp/test | xclip -i -selection clipboard -target image/png
`
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232618/gnome-screenshot-copy-clipboard-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04

Answer (score 0):

**Ubuntu 22.04**

`shift + ctrl + alt + r` opens `Record a screencast interactiveley`

go to **Settings** > **Keyboard** > **Keyboard shortcuts** > Sc**r**eenshots

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response but it is not what I was expecting. I use the version 20.04 and I am not trying to record my screen. The shortcuts are well set but the "Copy a screenshot of a window to clipboard" is just not working.

Comment: @WesB. I thought it might work for you, by the way, it can also take screenshots besides recordings.