# How to disable GNOME Screenshot UI, selection frame, necessity to click something to make a screenshot of an area in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, gnome-shell, screenshot

In Ubuntu 20.04 I could just press a shortcut, select an area and have that area in the buffer. Now it is gone and there is some annoying, irritating app.

[image: screenshot showing the screenshot app]

How to delete it? If I delete it will screenshots in Ubuntu work?

Comment: IMHO I too loved how it used to work. You could configure shortcuts to take a screenshot of a rectangle/windows/all screens and have it automatically save on the clipboard. It makes dealing with screenshots extremely fast. I understand that having a visual app can help newbies, but they should really implement a way to obtain the same behaviour as before for "pro" users, i.e. shortcuts immediately takes screenshot/selection and when it is done it is saved on the clipboard, no new window to close since you often just want to paste it in a chat/ticket right away

Comment: [Apparently](https://github.com/flameshot-org/flameshot/issues/2868#issuecomment-1212424959), screenshots in Gnome on **Wayland** (default on ubuntu 22.04) are broken like this until you get Gnome 43, which at least remembers the permissions... however, it seems to me like chances of getting Gnome 43 anytime soon on 22.04 LTS are low

Answer (score 8):

It functions pretty much the same now. You press <kbd>PtrSc</kbd>, then select the area you want a screenshot of, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> when done. The result is available both in the clipboard and as a file, so you do not need to worry ahead where you want the output.

You can reinstate the previous screenshot tool if you prefer, as indicated in the [answer of BeastOfCaerbannog](https://askubuntu.com/a/1425664/558158).

You can disable the default keyboard bindings to <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> (interactive screenshot), <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd> (whole screen) and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd> (current window) in "Settings" - "Keyboard" - "Keyboard Shortcuts", section "Screenshot" and replace them by your own under the section "Custom Shortcuts".

Note, however, that the functionality to transfer the output to the clipboard will not work if you run Wayland, the default for Ubuntu 22.04. That could still be implemented by a small script, that has `gnome-terminal` send a screenshot to a file, then uses `wl-copy` to place the output on the clipboard:

```
wl-copy < ~/Pictures/screenshot.png
```

Comment: It annoys me because I need to rearrange the area instead of picking one. If I want to use nearly the same area, it doesn't let me start a selection but instead makes me resize the area that is already there.

Comment: It is very personal, of course. I prefer the new approach - your comment about using nearly the same area according to me works better on the new version: the new tool will default to the same area as the previous screenshot, so it suffices to hit enter to capture exactly the same area of the screen.

Comment: @vanadium Note that there is a huge difference between "nearly the same" and "The same"... Having "nearly the same" area to screenshot means you might still need to modify the whole rectangle which is way slower by moving around the single sides/points than just selecting a new rectangle. Maybe they should add a button that if pressed it resets the area automatically, or maybe if you click+hold they should automatically restart rectangle selection

Comment: @GACy20 OP referred to "nearly the same", the tool selects "exactly the same", so eventually that same area can be moved slightly if needed. But otherwise I surely agree: selecting an area by dragging from one of the corners is faster than having to move different corners of a predefined selection.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot delete the new screenshot app, as it is built-in to GNOME Shell. However, you can install the `gnome-screenshot` app, which is the app that was used in Ubuntu before 22.04, using this command:

```
sudo apt install gnome-screenshot
```

You also need to install `xclip`, as suggested by [Ben](https://askubuntu.com/users/1112541/ben) in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1263786/618353)<sup>1</sup>:

```
sudo apt install xclip
```

Then go to Settings → *Keyboard* → *View and Customize Shortcuts* → *Custom Shortcuts*, click the <kbd>+</kbd> icon and add a new shortcut using the following as *Command*:

```
gnome-screenshot -a -c
```

The above command allows for selecting an area and saving directly to the clipboard, as you can find from [`man gnome-screenshot`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/gnome-screenshot.1.html):

```
-c, --clipboard
       Send the grab directly to the clipboard.

-a, --area
       Grab an area of the screen instead of the entire screen.
```

**Note:** Since `xclip` is an X11 command, this answer does not work on Wayland.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Without `xclip` the screenshot is not saved to the clipboard due to [a bug](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-screenshot/-/issues/66). Related question: [Gnome Screenshot Copy Clipboard not working on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232618/gnome-screenshot-copy-clipboard-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04) (specifically [Zexiang Liu's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1233926/618353)).</sup>