# Do not save screenshot as file (22.04)

Tags: 22.04, screenshot

For privacy reasons, it is important that screenshots are NOT saved as a file (only clipboard), but this is not possible anymore in the last upgrade.

**Any way to get the old behavior back?**

EDIT:
I tried to add a custom shortcut with command `gnome-screenshot -a -c`, but it does not save anything to clipboard. See [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196914/gnome-screenshot-cant-copy-to-clipboard-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Answer (score 1):

From [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/1212806/428280), one can use this dirty workaround:

1. Open settings > Keyboard > View and customize shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts.
2. Then add a new shortcut:

- Name: `gnome-screenshot`
- Command:

  `sh -c "gnome-screenshot -af /tmp/clipboard-img.png && xclip -i -selection clipboard -target image/png /tmp/clipboard-img.png && rm /tmp/clipboard-img.png"`
- Shortcut: whatever suits you

Comment: That does save to disk... and it IS possible to lock and copy the file before the rm :-)

Comment: This isn't perfect, but changing /tmp to /dev/shm may help this work better (it still risks screenshot data being saved to the swapfile IIRC).

Comment: `gnome-screenshot -c` ??

Comment: gnome-sick? Use the xfce4-screenshooter.