# How to copy area screenshot to clipboard on Kubuntu 18.04?

Tags: kubuntu, shortcut-keys, clipboard, screenshot

You can take a screenshot from a selected area in Kubuntu with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd>. The only problem is that this saves the image to `~/Pictures` by default so you have to open `~/Pictures` in your file manager and then copy/paste or drag and drop the image into the desired application.

[In Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/597926/323990) you have the ability to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd> to copy to the clipboard. Is there a way to do this in Kubuntu 18.04? I checked the default available shortcuts in *System Settings > Shortcuts* but I did not find shortcuts similar to the ones Ubuntu has.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and answer to include which version of Kubuntu is relevant.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### tl;dr

Just create a shortcut for `spectacle -rbc`.

### Explanation

Kubuntu uses Spectacle for screenshots. If you run `spectacle -h` you can see all the options it supports. We need these options:

```
-r, --region        Capture a rectangular region of the screen
-b, --background    Take a screenshot and exit without showing the GUI
-c, --clipboard     In background mode, copy screenshot to clipboard
```

So just create a shortcut for `spectacle -rbc`. If you prefer the GUI to popup, then create a shortcut for `spectacle -r`. In GUI mode you still have a button that copies the capture to the clipboard and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> works too!

### Tutorial

1. Launch Custom Shortcuts by one of these ways:

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and search for "Custom Shortcuts".
- Open the start menu (<kbd>Super</kbd>) and search for "Custom Shortcuts".
- Open the start menu (<kbd>Super</kbd>) and launch *Settings > System Settings*  then go to *Workspace > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts*.

1. Select "Screenshots" (if it doesn't exist create it under *Edit > New Group*) then *Click Edit > New > Global Shortcut > Command/URL*.
2. Name it and give it a comment like "Take Rectangular Region Screenshot".
3. Set the shortcut in the "Trigger" tab to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd> or whatever you want.
4. In the "Action" tab paste the command: `spectacle -rbc` or `spectacle -r` for the GUI version.
   [image: Custom Shortcuts setting shortcut action to command]
5. Press "Apply" and you are ready to use your shortcut.

You can do the same for "Take Active Window Screenshot" just use the command `spectacle -abc`.

### Usage

After pressing the shortcut, you can do your rectangular selection by clicking and dragging, then take the screenshot with <kbd>Enter</kbd> or by double clicking the selected area. There are other actions you can do at this stage that will be displayed at the bottom of the monitor:

[image: Taking a screenshot]

After taking the screenshot with `spectacle -rbc` a notification will be shown saying that "a screenshow was saved to your clipboard". With `spectacle -r` Spectacle will open and you can use its buttons or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

[image: Spectacle captured area in rectangle mode]

Comment: When the GUI starts, after you select the area, you first need to double click the area and then you will be able to copy.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 20.4 comes with a shortcut already prepared to take a screenshot
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Print</kbd> which will copy to the clipboard.

[image: Screenshot of keyboard shortcuts]

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu had this functionality since years. I even brought it up in the question. I asked about **K**ubuntu here.